# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: response is not defined

Tags: javascript

```
function getMovies() {
    return fetch('http://localhost:3000/movies').then(
        response =>{
          if(response.status===200){         
                  return response.json();          
          }
          else if(response.status == 404){
              return Promise.reject(new Error('Invalid URL'))
              done();
          }
          }).then(moviesListResponse =>{
            moviesList = moviesListResponse;  
              displaymoviesList(moviesList);
              return moviesListResponse;
          }).catch(error => {
            return response.status(404).json({message: 'an error occur'}, error.message);
            done();
          });
```

I am getting the below error:

```
(node:472) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: response is not defined
    at C:\Visual Studio_JavaScript\javascript-movie-cruiser-assignment\public\js\script.js:20:4
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:472) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_reject`enter code here`ions_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:472) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: Where exactly is line 20 of script.js…?

Comment: what is the use of done() if you have return on line-1? your response is not defined in the catch block, you don;'t need return

Comment: In this line `return response.status(404).json({message: 'an error occur'}, error.message);` where is `response` coming from ? Its not declared on top

Comment: Line no 20;: return response.status(404).json({message: 'an error occur'}, error.message);

Comment: What do you think that should do?

Comment: @KunalMukherjee

Comment: response should be from json data as below:  "movies": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "ACTION",
      "posterPath": "../images/The_Unique_Lama.jpg",
      "favourite": false
    },